# How to use sed substitution in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get the unique file name before the `"_"`, and copy only those files. Below is the script, but I must be missing something about the `sed`

Example of my file name - P2.D2.C00_21, P2.D2.C00_22

```
#!/bin/bash   

echo "Step 1"
names=$(ls ./Folder1 | sed 's//.*_//' | uniq)

echo "Step 2"    
for name in `echo $names`
do
    echo "Step 3"
    files=($(ls -v ./Folder1/${name}.* | xargs -n1 basename))
    echo "step 4"
    cp -f ./Folder1/${files[${#files[@]} - 1]} ./folder2
    echo "step 5"
done
```

Comment: Thanks to give a sample output

Comment: Please see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: ...also, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls/#echo_.24foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one finds the part after `_`:

```
 sed 's//.*_// # should be 's/_.*//'
```

but since you are globbing after uniq, I don't see the benefit of sed at all. Also, using `ls` is a very bad practice, you should rely in globbing instead.

If you don't mind using Perl:

```
for (glob("Folder1/*")) {
    ($a,$b,$c)=/((.*)_(.*))/;
    push @{$h{$b}}, $c; 
}
for $b(keys %h) {
    system("cp '${b}_$h{$b}[-1]' folder2/");
}
```

Comment: i hava a file which has same name with diffrent versions in its file name , Example P0.D.C0_21, P0.D.C0_22 were 22 is the latest version and i am trying to copy only those files

Comment: do you want to copy latest versions only?

Comment: wih ls ./Source | sed 's/_.*//' | uniq i am geting all the unique files then i am try ing to look for the version, is it not the right approach

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the wrong way :

- don't use a for loop to iterate on files to prevent bugs with `word spliting`. Instead, use `find` or a while loop
- don't parse `ls` output in your scripts, use *globs* instead